# How do I convert the decimal value in hex string and hex string and hex string to byte

Tags: c#, hex, byte

I have bytes array of decimal values like `[0, 4, 20, 141]` and I want that to be converted as `[0x00, 0x04, 0x14, 0x8D]` which I need to use this array as bytes to add in a buffer

Current data:

```
byte[] packet = new byte[4];

packet[0] = 0;
packet[1] = 4;
packet[2] = 20;
packet[3] = 141;
```

and expected data to send to the serial port is as below:

```
byte[] mBuffer = new byte[4];

mBuffer[0] = 0x02;
mBuffer[1] = 0x04;
mBuffer[2] = 0x14;
mBuffer[3] = 0x8D;
```

Tried:

```
Convert.ToByte(string.Format("{0:X}", packet[0]));
```

But throwing an exception:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: where this `packet[0]` comes from ?

Comment: @er-sho I am reading bytes from `.bin` file and slice the 16-16 bytes which are decimal values but I want to pass it as `0x00` like this

Comment: Very unclear what you trying to do... You start with array of 4 bytes... which you want to convert to array of 4 bytes... which you want to convert to some strings and then back to presumably array of 4 bytes. Maybe showing desired result can clarify what you want to achieve...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Sorry, I am also new to this:) Updated the question!

Comment: I've provided an answer which might help, but it seems odd that you're trying to do this conversion, when the numbers are already equal - Just formatted differently

Comment: @PrashantPimpale ??? What is the difference between "Current data:" and "expected data"  - both are exactly the same (short of 0 vs. 0x02 which may be just typing mistake)?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I am working on the WPF application where I need to write data on serial port

Comment: @PrashantPimpale so... it still does not explain anything. For some reason you see difference between two representation of the same value in the source code  - `140` and `0x8d` - please explain what it is and how you expect it to matter when code runs.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the exception because you're trying to substitute a variable in the string without the "$" prefix. Try this:

```
// Converts integer 141 to string "8D"
String parsed = String.Format($"{0:X}", packet[3]);
```

Then, you should be able to convert to a byte using this:

```
// Parses string "8D" as a hex number, resulting in byte 0x8D (which is 141 in decimal)
Byte asByte = Byte.Parse(parsed, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

Comment: When I use this for int `141` it give me `0` as bytes

Comment: are you saying that if I pass `141` instead `8d` and will work?

Comment: I've updated my answer to help explain what type/value each variable represents at each step

Comment: Thanks for your help, but still getting `0` in `asByte` variable here is [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=2iUj93QaBA)

Comment: Stuck into this: where I have `141` I want to convert it to `0x8D`